# How to generate static HTML documentation with swagger-js?

Tags: javascript, sdk, swagger

I have a RESTful API with Swagger integrated in it, so can now use a browser to point at that server and see the Swagger UI documenting that API.  I want to use the swagger-js project to generate a client side SDK in Javascript from the Swagger data on the server.

It appears to work to generate this client side SDK, and I can explore the SDK object by object and function by function in Chrome Developer Tools.  However, I'd like to somehow generate documentation for this client side SDK so users can read it to find the calls they want to make without having to explore laboriously in their browser development environment.

For example, if my client side SDK has been generated from the Swagger data and has these methods:

```
PetStore.addPet(petData)
PetStore.updatePet(petId, petData)
PetStore.deletePet(petId)
```

I'd like to have static documentation that users can read to know about these.  Is this possible?

Swagger-codegen project has a switch to generate static HTML documentation when making an SDK in a given language, but strangely it does not support Javascript and instead leaves that to the swagger-js project which seems to have no way to make static documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [1] jsdoc to generate the documentation for the auto-generated javascript client SDK. The quality of this documentation depends on the code comments in the javascript code so it will most likely not be good quality documentation. But try it out.

[1] http://usejsdoc.org/

Comment: This seems like a good idea, thanks Vineet I'll give it a try tomorrow!  Will report back how well it worked with the swagger-js generated client.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work because the client side SDK is generated dynamically at run time from the swagger JSON.  So you never have a .js file of the SDK objects to run through JSDoc.  The swagger-js project doesn't seem to provide a static client, and I can't run the objects through JSON.serialize to make a file because they have circular structures.

Comment: Yes sorry can you use https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen which generates javascript code for nodejs or angularjs. There is no vanilla javascript static code generator for swagger.

Comment: That worked thanks!  The downside is it's angular only and some clients may not want to use angular, but I think it's the best solution currently available.

Comment: Yes unfortunately its not vanilla javascript. One option to jsdoc is yuidoc which has nicer looking themes.